# JWE Invalid Invalid Initialization Vector length

Tags: python, encryption, aes

I need to encrypt using Python with the A256GCM algorithm, and getting back a JWT that I need to send to a Typescript backend, that then needs to decrypt it and consume its content.

This is the code that in the backend is used to decrypt what is received:

```
import { jwtDecrypt } from 'jose'
result = await jwtDecrypt(request.data, this.key)
```

And this is the code that I use on the Python application to encode and then send the code to the backend.

```
self.key = secrets.token_bytes(32)
self.b64s = base64.b64encode(self.key).decode('utf-8')

data_payload = json.dumps(self.payload)
self.token = jwe.encrypt(data_payload, self.key,
           algorithm='dir', encryption='A256GCM').decode('utf-8')
```

I tried to see if what arrives and what I produced are the same, and I find out that the backend receives exactly what I am sending, and the transmission of data is working correclty.

Here is an example of generated data

- key: BUCHFQE9nxIo4TwT613Xxm9wZ3U0zOmF7x7La2DBNj0=
- JWT: eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIn0..Fld1u1UAP0Hej4QM2bp1Og.1T854v93imiIlbFCVUCmMViZsSSb305u7cqDpj2LlITkfH0kjptcPGBK1OQtI5HjA9e6kjmQfuyUncDQ1wCxbCpY84Qe_jAnRorywdBMPxhwQZN860qJlkN4ZvOK8sLX-FgkKekw2Nmq3g09KjZpksYVtpkHEYB0zb7c2ZmMS4W7rvEk2K6YJoPtO3LX1ophhVNQVWWQljF1T60RoKgf_dPOGDMb051raN-w5aPykv9Da62_GGQtv6c6o5vMd7VNiBQaQ2uqEELikQ-85RgFZoX-8rieuEyR6O622ocCWDR0En6DrFenXYBk74K4WffiPAqpun0.QcN5OfrTGIFPkwzwiE3Png

But then, when is time to decrypt in the backend, it says the following error:

```
JWEInvalid: Invalid Initialization Vector length
```

I have not used an iv anywhere, and in the implementation of the server, (i have to stick with it, I cannot change since is third party) is not required it.

Do you have some idea where the problem might be? How could I fix this?

One thing that popped to my mind was that JWE is not the same as JWT, so I tried to use that library in Python, but this does not work, since `jose` does not implement jet the A256GCM algorithm.

Does someone have some idea or pointer? Thank you a lot

Comment: Seems to be a bug in python-jose: The library uses a 16 bytes IV for GCM (see [issue #281](https://github.com/mpdavis/python-jose/issues/281)), while the specification makes the 12 bytes IV length recommended for GCM mandatory (see [RFC 7518, sec. 5.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7518#section-5.3)).